# undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, csv, split

I am trying to split a row from a `CSV` file into an array. I can print out all the contents from the `CSV` file to the console no problem, like this:

```
CSV.foreach('so1.csv', :headers => true, :col_sep => "\t", :skip_blanks => true) do |row|
  id, name = row[0], row[1]
  puts id, name
end
```

However, when I try to split `name` i.e. `row[1]` into an `names` array, I get a `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` message:

```
CSV.foreach('so1.csv', :headers => true, :col_sep => "\t", :skip_blanks => true) do |row|
  id, name = row[0], row[1]
  unless (id =~ /#/)
    names = name.split
  end
```

I have also tried `name.split("\n")` and `name.split("\t")` to no avail.

For clarity, a screenshot of the `CSV` file:

[image: CSV Screenshot]

[CSV Screenshot](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2876/10195130496_772dd67673.jpg)

Could anybody shed any light on what is going wrong here? It would be great - thanks.

Comment: Your `puts id, name` doesn't tell you for sure that the entire row didn't go into `row[0]`. So that's probably what's happening, and `name` is `nil`. The entire row is in `id`. You need `:col_sep => ','`.

Comment: Please don't give us screen shots of data we'd need to reproduce the problem. Instead, copy, then paste, the sample data into your question, where we can copy it. Imagine how difficult it will be to understand your question when the image's link breaks and it's no longer visible.

Comment: @theTinMan fair point, will do in future.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that `name` is `nil`, probably because `row[1]` doesn't exist. My guess is the columns aren't being split properly. Right now you're saying that columns are separated by tabs but that's not what the screenshot is showing.

Are you sure you don't want `:col_sep => ","`?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I do, I changed it to `","` as you said. When outputting to the console it prints out `ID` and `name` on seperate lines rather than on one line as before. In terms of `split` error, it is no more.. Now I have a new error, but it is on a method on the next line, so this is progress I think..thanks